How to get the val dataloader in the on_validation_epoch_end function of pytorch_lightning?
I am learning to use pytorch_lightning to train a model, and I want to get the val dataloader in on_validation_epoch_end function to perform some additional operations on the validation data. But I can't seem to find the api to get the datalaoder. Is there a way to access the dataloader directly?
What I am doing now is to use val dataloader as a parameter of the model. I'm worried about whether there will be problems with this approach in the distributed mode.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Inside a Lightning Module, you can use self.trainer.val_dataloaders. More details at https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/data/access.html
